# Back Button is Unresponsive after Receiving Object from Other Activity

Tags: java, android, navigation

Let's say my first activity has the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == SET_PLAN_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            fixedPlan = data.getParcelableExtra("fixedPlan");
            recreate();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crop_rotation_planner);
    // Hide the action bar; I don't want to see that hideous thing, yet.
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    // Initialize imageLoader
    MainActivity.imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
    restore(savedInstanceState);
}

private void restore(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Check if activity has been launched previously
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Get saved crop rotation plan
        fixedPlan = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("fixedPlan");
        // Enable or disable btnViewPlan
        checkIfEnoughCropFamilies();
        // Set number of crop families
        setNumberOfCropFamilies();
        // get mSoilTypesList
        mSoilTypesList = (ArrayList<String>) savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("mSoilTypesList");
        selectedTypeOfSoil = savedInstanceState.getString("selectedTypeOfSoil");
        mPlantList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("mPlantList");

        // if mSoilTypesList hasn't been acquired, then execute loadSoilTypesFromNet to fetch data
        if (mSoilTypesList == null) {
            loadSoilTypesFromNet.execute();
        }
        // else if mSoilTypesList already exists, just display the soil types
        else {
            // only display if user hasn't selected soil yet
            if (selectedTypeOfSoil == null) {
                displaySoilTypes();
            }
            // if user has already selected soil type, then display plants
            else {
                getPlants();
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        loadSoilTypesFromNet.execute();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList("mSoilTypesList", mSoilTypesList);
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("mPlantList", mPlantList);
    savedInstanceState.putString("selectedTypeOfSoil", selectedTypeOfSoil);
    savedInstanceState.putParcelable("fixedPlan", fixedPlan);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    dismissAlertDialog();
    dismissProgressDialog();
    loadPlantsFromNet.cancel(true);
    loadSoilTypesFromNet.cancel(true);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!fixedPlan.isEmpty()) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CropRotationPlannerActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.str_dbox_exit_crp_title);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.str_dbox_exit_crp_message);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.str_dbox_exit_crp_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
                CropRotationPlannerActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.str_dbox_exit_crp_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alert = builder.create();
        alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.show();
    }
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

And my proceeding activity has the following important code:

```
    // We'll be sending our fixedPlan back to previous activity (CropRotationPlannerActivity)
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO :: THINK OF THE SAVE FEATURE
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.str_dbox_exit_title);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.str_dbox_exit_message);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.str_dbox_exit_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            intent.putExtra("fixedPlan", fixedPlan);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            // TODO : Somewhat buggy code here?
            // TODO : Takes quite sometime to process :/
            finish();
            PlanActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.str_dbox_exit_no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
            PlanActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.str_dbox_exit_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setCancelable(false); // so as to prevent the back button from closing the dialog box
    alert = builder.create();
    alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); // prevents user from canceling dialog box by clicking outside
    alert.show();
}
```

When the user exits the first activity and the Object `fixedPlan` doesn't have any contents, I want the user to exit to the main menu. When it doesn't have any contents, I want to pop a `DialogBox` so that the user is aware that the current activity contains important info and ask the user one more time if he really wants to exit.

To get to the next activity, `fixedPlan` should not be empty. And getting out from that activity, `fixedPlan` is never empty, too. But why does the back button not respond once the user goes back to the previous activity? What should I do?

**NOTE THAT THIS ONLY HAPPENS WHEN** positive button is pressed ( in the second activity). Another thing is that once I have pressed the positive button on the second activity, and the moment I'm in the first activity, and then I go back there and press the negative button, the back button works. It's really an issue with the positive button. BTW, I can feel the back button's vibration when pressed. LOL. Just that. It doesn't respond.

Adding `finish()` does not work either (to the else statement in my `onBackPressed` method for the first activity).

Comment: did your dialog shows in your first activity after positive button pressed from second activity?

Comment: it does totally nothing? or it closes your activity?

Comment: Nothing at all. I just can feel that the back button has received my tap because of the sound, but it does nothing.

Comment: what is the `recreate()` function?

Comment: It's a function from Android that basically recreates the activity. Somewhat like resetting it. I did not customize that function.

Comment: noticed a bug which may not be directly related to this issue: you should call `super.onSaveInsatanceState()` in your `onSaveInstanceState()`

Comment: Fixed it now. However, that unfortunately does not fix my problem. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing adding `dialog.dismiss()` before `finish()` in Positive button click event inside the second activity?

Also, I believe you should remove the calls to `PlanActivity.super.onBackPressed();`, both under positive and negative buttons click.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but that did not solve my problem at all. I'm sorry I was only able to reply now; been busy a while ago.